# Is it possible to get the domain of a user without Windows Authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I believe I know the answer but my boss thinks otherwise.  I need to be able to be able to pull the current visitors domain that they are currently signed into using User.Identity.  I am certain windows authentication must be enabled but my boss believes he accomplished this feat before without it. I just want to confirm.  The website must allow anonymous access, figure out which domain a user is coming from (AD domain) and redirect them to the appropriate sites.

Turned on widows auth, success.  Turned on anonymous with win auth, failure.  Turned off windows auth, turned on anonymous access failure.

Site has to be anonymous to allow all users to visit it due to the political nature of our business.

```
            userInfo = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');
            if (userInfo.Length > 0)
            {
                domainName = userInfo[0];
                userID = userInfo[1];
            }
```

User.Identity is null when windows auth is off.  Users are prompted to provide authentication when it is on.

Comment: You cannot identify the domain the user's computer is attached to unless the server and user's machines are part of the same domain and the user is authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your site returns a 401 challenge (i.e. some authentication needed) then you will have no access to any identity data.

The user will always be anonymous.